# How to group and rank with reference to another column

Tags: vb.net, linq, grouping, vb.net-2010, rank

I need help in grouping or partitioning and ranking according to the subject. Every subject must have first to last student.
I am using the code below with VB 2010.

```
Dim TotaledRecords = From p In db.Assessments
Where p.Class = cboclass.Text And p.Stream = cbostream.Text
Select p
Order By p.Total Descending

For j = 1 To TotaledRecords.Count
TotaledRecords.ToList(j - 1).Position = j
Next
db.SubmitChanges()
```

I want it to restart the ranking with respect to the subject.

See attached picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should order by subject first and then by total. 
Like this:

```
Order By p.Subject, p.Total Descending
```

If you want to add a field with the rank grouped by Subject, one way to do it would be like this:

```
rank =(From r In db.Assessments _
     Order By r.Subject, r.Total _
     Where (r.Subject = p.Subject) _
     And (r.Total > p.Total) _
     Select r).Count + 1 _
```

... and the linq query would be like this:

```
Dim TotaledRecords = From p In db.Assessments _
Where p.Class = cboclass.Text And p.Stream = cbostream.Text _
Select p, _
rank =(From r In db.Assessments _
       Order By r.Subject, r.Total _
       Where (r.Subject = p.Subject) _
       And (r.Total > p.Total) _
       Select r).Count + 1 _
Order By p.Subject, p.Total Descending
```

Comment: Yea it worked. I now need the program to give the same ranking to two same value under total e.g. If two people get 60  it should give all of them same rank value.

Comment: I have edited the answer with the rank value for same values in group "Subject"